# MongoDB count distinct items in an array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My `actors` collection contains an array-of-documents field, called `acted_in`. Instead of returning the size of `acted_in.idmovies` like so: `{$size: $acted_in.idmovies}`, I want to return the number of distinct values inside `$acted_in.idmovies`. How can I do that ?

```
c1 = actors.aggregate([{"$match": {'$and': [{'fname': f_name},
                                            {'lname': l_name}]}},
                       {"$project": {'first_name': '$fname',
                                     'last_name': '$lname',
                                     'gender': '$gender',
                                     'distinct_movies_played_in': {'$size': '$acted_in.idmovies'}}}])
```

Comment: You can use `$setDifference` with `[]` which will remove the duplicates. Something like `distinct_movies_played_in': {'$size': { $setDifference: [ '$acted_in.idmovies', []] }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
actors.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {fname: f_name, lname: l_name}
    }, 
    {
        $unwind: '$tags'
    }, 
    {
        $group: {
                    _id: '$_id', 
                    first_name: {$first: '$fname'}, 
                    last_name: {$last: '$lname'}, 
                    gender: {$first: '$gender'}, 
                    tags: {$addToSet: '$tags'}
                }
    }, 
    {
        $project: {
                      first_name: 1, 
                      last_name: 1, 
                      gender: 1, 
                      distinct: {$size: '$tags'}
                  }
    }
])
```

After the `tags` array is deconstructed and then put back into a set of itself, then you just need to get the number of items or length of that set.

Answer (score 7):

You basically need to include [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) in there to obtain the "distinct" items. All "sets" are "distinct" by design and by obtaining the "difference" from the present array to an empty one `[]` you get the desired result. Then you can apply the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/).

You also have some common mistakes/misconceptions. Firstly when using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) or any MongoDB query expression you do not need to use `$and` unless there is an explicit case to do so. **All** query expression arguments are "already" AND conditions unless explicitly stated otherwise, as with `$or`. So don't explicitly use for this case.

Secondly your [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) was using the explicit field path variables for every field. You do not need to do that just to return the field, and outside of usage in an "expression", you can simply use a `1` to notate you want it included:

```
c1  = actors.aggregate([
 { "$match": { "fname"': f_name, "lname": l_name } },
 { "$project": {
   "first_name": 1,
   "last_name": 1,
   "gender": 1,
   "distinct_movies_played_in": { 
     "$size": { "$setDifference": [ "$acted_in.idmovies", [] ] }
   } 
  }}
])
```

In fact, if you are actually using MongoDB 3.4 or greater ( and your notation of an element within an array `"$acted_in.idmovies"` says you have at least MongoDB 3.2 ) which has support for [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) then use that instead of specifying all other fields in the document.

```
c1  = actors.aggregate([
 { "$match": { "fname"': f_name, "lname": l_name } },
 { "$addFields": {
   "distinct_movies_played_in": { 
     "$size": { "$setDifference": [ "$acted_in.idmovies", [] ] }
   } 
  }}
])
```

Unless you explicitly need to just specify "some" other fields.

The basic case here is **do not use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** for array operations unless you specifically **need** to perform a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operation on with it's `_id` key pointing at a value obtained from "within" the array.

In all other cases, MongoDB has far more efficient operators for working with arrays that what `$unwind` does.

Comment: Useful insight about the inefficiency of the `$unwind` operator. Your solution  would indeed be more efficient than mine!

Comment: Thank you for: `$countDistinct = $size: { $setDifference: ['$myArray', []] }`